Multiple types of resources
I would like to create and use a type of resources Operators. They are stored in an Excel database with 2 columns : name and quantity (for example 3 operator1, 4 operator2 ...).
I managed to import it in a collection OperatorsCollection. I would like to be able to use 1 operator3 in a block Service for example.
How is it possible? Can I create a resource pool by type of operator using Java (I can have many types of operators)?
I tried a resourcepool + a agent type using the database Excel, but impossible to choose in detail within Service block a specific type of operator.

If all those operators are actually "similar", you should only have 1 agent type Operator and manually create 1 resource pool for each data row. Consider adding a column type to distinguish them if needed.
Even if you have a dozen rows, this will be (far) easier than trying this programmatically (unless you are very advanced)
If you have more than ~25 rows, though, it would be easier to:

create an agent type OperatorPool with 1 ResourcePool block
instantiate 1 OperatorPool for each row
seize from the ResourcePool block in your OperatorPool agents

